# regarding the usage of tf.app.flags.DEFINE_enum

Tags: tensorflow

In a program, I saw the following code segment

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_enum('image_format', 'png', ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
                         'Image format.')
```

But I was not able to find the definition of usage of `tf.app.flags.DEFINE_enum`, what does it used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This makes a command line parameter which is called `image_format`, with a default of `png`, and which can take the values `png`, `jpeg` or `jpg`. In the program help string, the flag will be explained as simply "Image format.".

From the docstring:

Registers a flag whose value can be any string from `enum_values`.

Args:

- *name*: `str`, the flag name.
- *default*: `str|None`, the default value of the flag.
- *enum_values*: `[str]`, a non-empty list of strings with the possible values for the flag.
- *help*: `str`, the help message.
- ...